# Nvidia Smi JSON Output

Tags: json, node.js, xml, nvidia

I want to put in my system info about machine available GPU and status for real time monitoring.
I'm outputting as `XML` the GPU info using

```
$ nvidia-smi -x -q
```

This command will print output current GPU status (like usage, temperature, etc.) as well formatted XML (with defined DTD).
My XML output is [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/2620b777562c2dfd50d6b618b5f20867).

There is no option to output directly from `nvidia-smi` to json, so at this time the only option I see is to convert the XML to JSON from Node.js.

The problem is that I need it as JSON, so I'm trying to convert to JSON within my `Node` application. I have used in turn several npm available modules like xml2json, node-xml2js, etc. but having different errros with each of then (null, undefined, etc).
Using a simple DOMParser in the browser (window.DOMParser) will work instead.
It seems to be an error with this XML since when I have one GPU output like [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/6e98a3afe62f5365145135cb60021b81) the JSON is converted fine as showed in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/341355ff00f2d79c5a062acd1f6d5606).

I'm using node spawn to call the `nvdia-smi` command and then to parse the output like:

```
(function() {

var XMLParser = require('./xml2json');

function gpuInfo() {
    var _data='';
    var curl = require('child_process').spawn('nvidia-smi', ['-x','-q']);
    curl.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
        _data+= new Buffer(data,'utf-8').toString();
     });
    curl.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
        var x2js = new XMLParser();
        var json = x2js.xml_str2json( _data );
        console.log(JSON.stringify( json,null,2));
    });
    curl.on('exit', function(code) {
        if (code != 0) {
            console.log('Failed: ' + code);
        }
    });

}
module.exports = {
    gpuInfo:gpuInfo    
}
```

In this case I'm using a [modified](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/680b11d056e589f7ec6d8990f1a7fd8d) version of xml2json browser client module combined with the `xmldom` module, but it seems not be a stable solution, so my parsing is done here like:

```
this.parseXmlString = function(xmlDocStr) {
            if (xmlDocStr === undefined) {
                return null;
            }
            var xmlDoc;
            var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;        
            var parsererrorNS = null;
            try {
                xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString( xmlDocStr, "text/xml" );
                if( parsererrorNS!= null && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(parsererrorNS, "parsererror").length > 0) {
                    xmlDoc = null;
                }
            }
            catch(err) {
                xmlDoc = null;
            }
            return xmlDoc;
        };
```

Are out of here

1. Another way to obtain these info as json?
2. A more efficient solution via some robust XML / JSON parser module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use https://github.com/Cheedoong/xml2json
It is more quickly and can use as binary tools like jq.
And you will run like that:

```
nvidia-smi -x -q | xml2json | jq
```

And result will be like:

```
{
  "nvidia_smi_log": {
    "timestamp": "Thu Aug 29 13:45:26 2019",
    "driver_version": "387.34",
    "attached_gpus": "9",
    "gpu": [
      {
        "@id": "00000000:03:00.0",
        "product_name": "P106-090",
        "product_brand": "GeForce",
        "display_mode": "Disabled",
        "display_active": "Disabled",
        "persistence_mode": "Enabled",
        "accounting_mode": "Disabled",
        "accounting_mode_buffer_size": "1920",
        "driver_model": {
          "current_dm": "N/A",
          "pending_dm": "N/A"
        },
        "serial": "N/A",
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created this tool to convert nvidia-smi xml output to json.
https://github.com/fffaraz/nvidia-smi-json